# 'CREATE TABLE' generates Run-time error '3290'

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a syntax issue in the first `CREATE TABLE` statement.

I'm receiving the following VBA error:

> Run-time error '3290'

The goal is to move the distinct data to a new table dependent on values in specific columns. Afterwards the original table is cleared, and every distinct value will be inserted again. The temporary table will be deleted afterwards.

```vb
' ** Issue here ** '
db.Execute ("CREATE TABLE tTemp AS (SELECT DISTINCT History_Date, Sedol, Selskabsnavn, MarketCap, JQScore, JQ_Rank, Value_Rank, Quality_Rank, Momentum_Rank FROM JQHistory)")

db.Execute ("DELETE * FROM JQHistory")
db.Execute ("SELECT * FROM tTemp INTO JQHistory")
db.Execute ("DROP TABLE tTemp")
```

This code is being run from within MS Excel.

Comment: I'd rather create separate queries in Access, engineering their structure through visual designer and use `DoCmd.OpenQuery` method, or something like that. It is easier to fix possible errors in future

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just wondering.. may I ask why this question is tagged with `excel`?

Comment: Because the code is performed in Excel VBA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the syntax to make this work in the third statement, although it's not quite correct.

The first line should be 
`db.Execute ("SELECT DISTINCT <list of fields> INTO tTemp FROM JQHistory")`

The third statement should be:
`db.Execute ("INSERT INTO JQHistory SELECT <list of fields> FROM tTemp")`

Comment: This does indeed function!
However I've run into one issue following it. The table JQHistory does not reset auto-numbering ID's plus the newly inserted data is not grouped correctly, therefore the structure does not take into account which data is most recent.

Comment: I just did a quick search for resetting an Autonumber field in MS Access and found this: CurrentDb.Execute `ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER COLUMN myID COUNTER(1,1)`
As for the ordering, you're going to have to play around with the `SELECT` statements to achieve that - `ORDER BY History_Date` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you! The numbering is working. I will have to figure out a workaround since 'History_Date' is formatted as Text instead of date because of an previous issue. I will look into the previous issue and ```Order by History_Date``` :)

Comment: Maybe try `ORDER BY CDate(History_Date)` - you may get away with an on-the-fly conversion.  Alternatively, add an extra column to the first `SELECT`: something like `CDate(History_Date) AS Sort_Date` and then order by that.  But don't include it in the list of fields in the `SELECT` bit of the statement when you insert the data back into JQHistory.  Please also mark it as the answer if appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Final solution:

```
db.Execute ("SELECT DISTINCT History_Date, Sedol, Selskabsnavn, MarketCap, JQScore, JQ_Rank, Value_Rank, Quality_Rank, Momentum_Rank INTO tTemp FROM JQHISTORY ORDER BY History_Date")
db.Execute ("DELETE * FROM JQHistory")
db.Execute ("ALTER TABLE JQHistory ALTER COLUMN Id COUNTER (1, 1)")
db.Execute ("INSERT INTO JQHistory SELECT * FROM tTemp")
db.Execute ("DROP TABLE tTemp")
```

Comment: You deserve a medal just for the line initializing the counter: `db.Execute ("ALTER TABLE JQHistory ALTER COLUMN Id COUNTER (1, 1)")`. I also prefer `SELECT... INTO` rather `CREATE TABLE` in Access