# VBA Compare Excel data to Ms Access Table before inserting the record

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I already have a code to insert data from Excel to MS Access, the only problem is I need to identify if the data is unique compare to MS Access Table before I insert the data.

I consider it unique by combination of fields comparing all 25 Columns. I already have an idea but I think this is not the best one.

Table 1 = Main Table

Table 2 = Excel data

Table 3 = Blank Table (I will use this table to combine Table 1 & Table 2)

1. Upload excel data in different table in MS Access (Table 2)
2. Copy the Main Table (Table 1) and Table 2 to Table 3
3. Apply a Distinct query in Table 3

Hope someone can help. This is my code inserting data from Excel to access:

```vb
With Workbooks(MyWB).Sheets(MySH)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, RNG_PO_NUM).End(xlUp).Row

    If SAPLastRow <= SAP_START_ROW + 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Data in " & SAP_SHEET & " please check!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Upload all records from SAP Sheet to MS Access Database.
    For i = SAP_START_ROW + 1 To SAPLastRow
        rst.AddNew
        counter = 1
        For j = 1 To RNG_KEY
            If j = 3 Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                If Application.IsNA(.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                    .Cells(i, j).Value = "N/A"
                ElseIf Application.IsErr(.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                    .Cells(i, j).Value = "VALUE!"
                End If

                If .Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                    rst(rst.Fields(counter).Name) = Trim(.Cells(i, j).Value)
                    rst.Update
                End If
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: The idea would either be to have a unique key in your Access table (so you can't insert that key twice and get an error if you try to). For example if you define a field "article number" as unique in Access, then the article number cannot be inserted twice. • Or you run a SQL query with the data you want to insert and if there is a result then it already exists. • That's probably all we can tell, because your question has to less information to give a more detailed answer. • Give it a try.

Comment: What do you consider 'unique' - a single field or combination of fields such as first name, last name, birthdate, email, etc? Set a field or combination of fields as unique index in Access table and duplicates will not be permitted.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645798/create-table-generates-run-time-error-3290
This follows your logic of inputting all data, followed by deleting non-distinct data

Comment: Thank you for all your ideas and comments! I will try it. :)